# Why does the toString() method of an array return an empty string when the array contains a RegExp?

Tags: javascript, v8

```
> a = [1, /2/]
[ 1, /2/ ]
> a.toString()
''
> a = [1, 2]
[ 1, 2 ]
> a.toString()
'1,2'
```

Reproduced on `Chrome 104.0.5112.102` and `Node v16.17.0`. Not sure on other platforms.

Comment: Even weirder `[1, /2/].toString()` returns `"1,/2/"`. Seems to work differently for some reason!

Comment: I think it is something with the console. `var a = [1, /2/];
var b = a.toString();
console.log(b);` seems to log it fine.

Comment: `a.join()` and `[].join.call(a)` show the same behaviour

Comment: `Array.prototype.join` (which is used by `Array.prototype.toString`) is known to return an empty string if called on an array that contains itself. I suspect something similar is happening here, but I have no idea what the assignment to the variable `a` has to do with that. In any case, it's a bug that should be reported…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this was reported at [crbug.com/v8/13259](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=13259) a few days before this question was asked, and is being fixed.

The issue is specific to how the Node and DevTools REPLs are implemented. Inside regular scripts, or with the `d8` shell, everything is working as you would expect.